# hot deploy in embedded jetty

Tags: maven-2, jetty, spring-roo, maven-jetty-plugin, hotdeploy

I have a Spring Roo project and I use `mvn jetty:run` to run my app. The only problem is changes to the `*.java` classes do not hot deploy, while changes to `*.jspx` hot deploy fine.

So how can I configure mvn jetty to hotdeploy for java classes?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to set the [`scanIntervalSeconds`](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#scanIntervalSeconds) to a value greater than 0 to enable it:

> **`scanIntervalSeconds`** - The interval in seconds to scan the webapp for changes and restart the context if necessary. Ignored if reload is enabled. Disabled by default.
>   **Default value is**: 0.

So the configuration might looks like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.22</version>
  <configuration>
    <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Once enabled, the jetty maven plugin will scan the directory defined in [`classDirecory`](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#classesDirectory) (which points to `${project.build.outputDirectory}` by default i.e. `target/classes`) for changes.

You then just need to have your IDE compile classes in `target/classes` (or to run `mvn compile`) and Jetty will restart the context upon changes on Java classes.

Comment: There are 404 errors while Jetty redeploys the classes. Any suggestion how to avoid them? Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23343243/jetty-404-error-page-on-hot-deployment

Comment: Unfortunately redeployment with zero downtime requires a lot of effort in the Java world :( Edit: Will try this: http://www.rafaelsteil.com/zero-downtime-deploy-script-for-jetty/