# jetty 404 error page on hot deployment

Tags: jetty, jetty-9

I am currently using Jetty 9.1.4 on Windows.

When I deploy the war file without hot deployment config, and then restart the Jetty service. During that 5-10 seconds starting process, all client connections to my Jetty server are waiting for the server to finish loading. Then clients will be able to view the contents.

Now with hot deployment config on, the default Jetty 404 error page shows within that 5-10 second loading interval.

Is there anyway I can make the hot deployment has the same behavior as the complete restart - clients connections will wait instead seeing the 404 error page ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this does not seem to be possible currently after talking with the Jetty developers on IRC #jetty.

One solution I will try to use are two Jetty instances with a loadbalancing reverse proxy (e.g. nginx) before them and taking one instance down for deployment.

Of course this will instantly lead to new requirements (session persistence/sharing) which need to be handled. So in conclusion: much work to do in the Java world for zero downtime on deployments.

**Edit:** I will try this, seems like a simple enough solution http://rafaelsteil.com/zero-downtime-deploy-script-for-jetty/ Github: https://github.com/rafaelsteil/jetty-zero-downtime-deploy