# Spring MVC project doesn't respond to browser requests after code changes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, maven-jetty-plugin, jrebel

I have a basic Spring 4 MVC project setup. After starting the server the site is accessible and works until I change something in code and later it doesn't respond to any kind of requests(GET/POST) from the browser when I click links in my site to navigate. When I click login I get the following in my console,

```
DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/springapp/login]
[artifact:mvn] 2016-01-12 14:06:25 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:318 - Looking up handler method for path /login
```

The URL for login in my app is `http://localhost:8080/springapp/login`.

The same *"Looking up handler method for path `/something`"* message is shown for any subsequent requests but there is no response from the localhost server. I waited for 15 minutes but no response whatsoever. I use embedded jetty as my server in eclipse. I disabled the firewall and uninstalled the antivirus but that doesn't help.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>densoServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/springContext.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>densoServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

springContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans profile="dev" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp">
        <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="(service|controller|dao)\..*"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="css/**" location="/WEB-INF/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="js/**" location="/WEB-INF/js/" />

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
        <property name="additionalDialects">
           <set>
              <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
           </set>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        <property name="viewNames" value="*jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="2"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean name="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:i18n/messages" />
        <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
      <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
      <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
      <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.springapp.model"/>
      <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:com/springapp/mappers/*.xml" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
      <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
      <property name="basePackage" value="com.springapp.mappers" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My embedded maven-jetty configuration,

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
        <stopKey>siteStop</stopKey>
        <stopPort>9191</stopPort>
        <httpConnector>
          <host>0.0.0.0</host>
          <port>8080</port>
        </httpConnector>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have to restart the server every time to test my code which is time-consuming. What could be blocking the response from the server?

**EDIT**: The server stops responding only when I make changes in the code. After stopping the server it throws the thread couldn't be stopped,

```
[artifact:mvn] DEBUG DisposableBeanAdapter:327 - Invoking destroy method 'close' on bean with name 'sqlSession'
[artifact:mvn] WARN  DisposableBeanAdapter:361 - Invocation of destroy method 'close' failed on bean with name 'sqlSession'
[artifact:mvn] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Manual close is not allowed over a Spring managed SqlSession
[artifact:mvn]  at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.close(SqlSessionTemplate.java:333)
[artifact:mvn]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[artifact:mvn]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[artifact:mvn]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[artifact:mvn]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:354)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:277)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:972)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.destroySingletons(AbstractBeanFactory.java)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:979)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:982)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.destroy(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.destroyInstance(ServletHolder.java:449)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStop(ServletHolder.java:421)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:143)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:162)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:73)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doStop(ServletHandler.java:230)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:143)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:162)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:73)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStop(SecurityHandler.java:411)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStop(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:457)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:143)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:162)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:73)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStop(SessionHandler.java:127)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:143)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:162)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:73)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStop(ContextHandler.java:834)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStop(ServletContextHandler.java:258)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStop(WebAppContext.java:523)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStop(JettyWebAppContext.java:388)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:143)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:162)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:73)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:143)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:162)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:73)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.stop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:143)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStop(ContainerLifeCycle.java:162)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStop(AbstractHandler.java:73)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStop(Server.java:468)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.stop(AbstractLifeCycle.java:89)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ShutdownMonitor$ShutdownMonitorRunnable.stopLifeCycles(ShutdownMonitor.java:273)
[artifact:mvn]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ShutdownMonitor$ShutdownMonitorRunnable.run(ShutdownMonitor.java:172)
[artifact:mvn]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Jetty server exiting.
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Total time: 1:15:15.551s
[artifact:mvn] 2016-01-12 16:13:03.560:WARN:oejut.QueuedThreadPool:ShutdownMonitor: qtp340358109{STOPPING,8<=19<=200,i=0,q=2} Couldn't stop Thread[qtp340358109-58,5,main]
[artifact:mvn] 2016-01-12 16:13:03.560:WARN:oejut.QueuedThreadPool:ShutdownMonitor: qtp340358109{STOPPING,8<=19<=200,i=0,q=2} Couldn't stop Thread[qtp340358109-80,5,main]
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Final Memory: 33M/342M
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 75 minutes 20 seconds
```

Update:

I tested the same workspace in other systems it works fine there. So the code isn't the problem here. Its not the eclipse either since I used the STS and didn't get any response. I took a Thread dump on eclipse pid using the JDK's jVisualVM and following is the thread dump trace, http://pastebin.com/9HQFSebM

Comment: Did you try to check if the requests reach the server? meaning does the lookup find the correct controllers? Maybe some hidden from the logs OOM error?

Comment: Yes, I don't have a problem with that. It all works fine after starting the server.

Comment: start jconsole and monitor your server health.

Comment: when you mean code changes , you mean while the server is running ? have you set up the embedded jetty to hot-deploy the new class files? look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369851/hot-deploy-in-embedded-jetty

Comment: @AntJavaDev Yes, the server is started with embedded jetty and I meant the code changes after starting the jetty server and I have JRebel listening for code changes inside the `target\classes` directory. Code changes are not my problem. But the server response is blocked somehow which is what I'm not able to track of.

Comment: is there any starved thread pool or connection pool?? is there a cap on how you open connections ? because i dont see a managed datasource

Comment: JRebel does much more than reload simple code changes - it also reloads the changes in the frameworks. Assuming you're already using up-to-date version of JRebel, contact support@zeroturnaround.com, some integration might be misbehaving.

Comment: @AntJavaDev I've added an update to the question. You can see the thread dump of eclipse process. I don't see any blocking threads. Also the same workspace works fine in other systems. Based on this [bug 439123](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439123) even tried switching workspace but with no help.

Comment: ok based on @Henri Viik answer , what type of code change you perform ? are you changing the application Context ? or a simple change in a method

Comment: @AntJavaDev Its simple modification of anything in `.java` files(Controllers, Service and Dao methods basically).

Comment: To debug, you can try adding JVM argument `-Drebel.load_embedded_plugins=false`. This disables all JRebel plugins - if problem disappears after this, definitely contact the JRebel support.

Answer (score 0):

After a very long time I found out what the issue was. Contacting Jrebel support team as they suggested, I was using an old version(`JRebel Legacy Agent 6.2.1 (201506091436)`) of jrebel.

Upgrading to the latest version(`JRebel Legacy Agent 6.2.3`) solved my issue. Seems like there was some bug fixes with the newer version that I was not updated with.